# Load file jQuery load with css inside the file

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Imagine this small code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadingDiv").load("sub/__window_div.php");
})
```

It runs okay in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE8 (yes!). But if I add some CSS in the  `__window_div.php` file, it stops running in IE8, but runs fine on other browsers.

I just add in the file those lines:

```
<style type="text/css">
</style>
```

**Is it not possible to have CSS in the include file? Why only IE8 doesn't load the file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it is not valid to have `<style></style>` elements in any part of your HTML other than inside the  `<head></head>` tags.
2. Other browsers have managed to handle it, but as I said, the `style` element must be present only inside `head` tags.

Comment: Hello, I put <style type="text/css"></style> in the HEAD section of the included file, but the file was not loaded. If I remove this it loads, I will check your suggestions and give you feedback soon. Thanks

Comment: @Pedro: You cannot load an entire HTML document via `$.load()`, that's not the way it is supposed to work. You load parts of the document with it. Your CSS should be on the document which does the loading, not on the loaded one.

Comment: OKAY,Thank you, I will try this way. Indeed loading an entire HTML doc it is loading a segond HEAD tag and a segond BODY tag... maybe trouble comes from there. I will try thank you,

Comment: @Pedro: Glad I helped. Try that, and afterwards consider accepting an answer by clicking on the empty tick below the vote counts on the top left hand side of the answer. So, this question gets marked as resolved and others who will face the same issue will won't have a hard time finding it. If you need more details as to why you should accept an answer read [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)?

Answer (score 0):

You can not but  in the body.

You should try to add your style directly in the tag with style="" attribute.

Or you should have your style included in the css of the calling page. The style will be applied on the loaded content.

Comment: Sorry my anterior answer was cut... I have check and as Shef mentioned, it seems that IE doesnt like when I load an entire HTML document... The others browser well IE, seems not. Thans for your help.

Comment: It does not make sense to load an entire document. If you do so, you'll have 2 html, head, body, .... You should load only what you need in your target div